# Deleting m-to-m is also trying to cascade delete a one-2-one

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following Domains

```
class Committee {
   String name
   BoardCommitteeType boardCommitteeType
   Date dateCreated
   Date lastUpdated
   User createdBy
   User modifiedBy

   static belongsTo = [
      board: Board,
   ]

   static hasMany = [          
      members: User
   ]
}

class User {

    static hasMany = [            
        committees: Committee,     
    ]

    static belongsTo = [
        Board, Committee
    ]
}
```

The problem is that when I attempt to do a board.removeFromCommittees(committee) I'm getting the following exception:

deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.wbr.highbar.User#1];

I understand what that means.  What I don't understand is why I am getting it.  The other interesting bit is that if I make creatdBy and modifiedBy in the Committee instance null, the delete works just fine.  That's why I am thinking that GORM is trying cascade the one-2-one.  My theory is that is has something to do with the fact User belongsTo a Committee.  But I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: This approach is riddled with circular dependencies and that's what's causing the issues. Consider if you could refactor your domain model.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how the circular dependencies are the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The cascading delete is effected by the `belongsTo` relationships between your domain classes.

Since `Committee belongsTo Board`, when a Board gets deleted, the delete cascades to the Committee. Since `User belongsTo Committee`, when a Committee gets deleted, the delete cascades to the User.

The solution to your problem is to remove the `User belongsTo Committee` relationship.

*Notes on your domain model as a whole:*

You have a lot of many-to-many relationships. They're not necessarily wrong, but they might be overcomplicating things. You could probably get away with just using:

```
class Committee {
    static hasMany = [boards: Board, users: User]
}

class Board {
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    static belongsTo = Committee // this is the only belongsTo you need, since if a
                                 // committee is dissolved, presumably the board
                                 // will be dissolved as well (unless you have
                                 // cross-committee boards)
}

class User {
    // doesn't define any relationships,
    // let the Committee/Board domains handle everything

    // also, this is presuming that users are at a higher level than committees, i.e.
    // a user could belong to multiple committees
}
```

Comment: If I remove the User belongsTo Committee, Grails complains that I have no owning side to the M2M relationship.  So that does not solve my problem.  What I've done to solve this is I've removed the M2M completely, and write a CommitteeMembers class with a composite ID of user.id and committee.id.  To me, this is a limitation of how GORM implements M2M because there is rarely an "owning" side to it.

Comment: I do appreciate the help, however.

Comment: GORM and M2M relationships are always a bit fussy, and I've been in similar situations as you. Have you tried my suggestion for an alternate domain model? That would remove the M2M and also not require you to manually write the relationship domain.

Comment: @Rob - Yes and no.  I did change the domain but not the way you suggested.  I See my first comment on this answer.

Comment: Is the solution to this to use a join table : http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2%20Custom%20ORM%20Mapping

Comment: I would actually remove the belongsTo Board on User.

Comment: I'm not sure on the relationship you have between Board and Committee. I'm assuming 1-M. I would actually remove the belongsTo Board on User. It controls the cascade deletes. You already have a cascade on Committee. You can also tweak the cascade operations too. See: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2.9%20Custom%20Cascade%20Behaviour